# fast electrical switch

Tags: switches

i have a continuous train of ~ 20 ns electrical pulses (<1V p-p) with repetition rate of ~1KHz. I need to make a switch that allows 10 pulses to pass with minimum distortion and then blocks the next 10 pulses and repeat the cycle.[image]

Comment: Gimme dough, y'know?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency-divide the input signal by 10, then 2. Use the output of the latter stage as a pass/block signal. If your input signal isn't a proper digital signal, you may need a Schmitt trigger input and some ns delay circuit to account for the delay caused by the trigger level.